# How to mock to twitter api using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, mocking, ruby-mocha

I'm developing a application that uses the twitter API. I'm currently using rspec with mocha, but I found it to be cumbersome and I cannot reuse the mocking that I create for a give method. Is there a way that you can have for a give call, return something, and for another call return something else? Or it needs to be by each method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [webmock](http://github.com/bblimke/webmock) or fake mock.

It allows you to stub HTTP requests and setting expectations on HTTP requests in Ruby.